# Domino HTTP Task and long polling

Tags: http, lotus-notes, lotus-domino, long-polling

I have a web application running on Domino HTTP, which queries data from the user mail databases.

I would like to implement Long Polling, Direct Push, WebSockets or any similar technique into that application to get changes from the server instantly or with low delay (and without user interaction). Is this possible, and if so, how?

Right now, to get the data, I am using Notes agents which are called via HTTP, but of these there can only be finitely many at the same time (3 by default?), so I would have to find a non-blocking alternative.

Comment: What kind of data are you talking about, and across how many files. Not clear what the use-case is. Depending on the frequency you could be introducing performance problems on the server.

Comment: The limit on concurrent agent only applies to agents that run under the AMGR task. If you are calling them via HTTP, there's no limit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have access to make changes to the mailfiles/mailserver you could one of few things.

- You could explore using [Triggerhappy](https://www.openntf.org/main.nsf/project.xsp?r=project/Trigger%20Happy/) which is a low level event trigger mechanism that needs server side setup
- You can run the agent within the mailfile and trigger it on before/after new mail event. You would need to set this up on each mailin
- The simplest way might be to poll. Setup [Data access services](https://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/ddwiki.nsf/xpAPIViewer.xsp?lookupName=IBM%20Domino%20Access%20Services%209.0.1#action=openDocument) and keep polling the api over http
- Last resort, you can setup an agent in the mail.box

Comment: Update: We went for normal polling.